# Is there a name for the practice of dropping articles in legal writing?

Tags: terminology, articles, legalese

I see this a lot in legal writing.

> "The defendant will be required to pay $1000 in restitution."

vs.

> "Defendant will be required to pay $1000 in restitution."

Or,

> Upon arrival, police noticed a foul smell in the air.

vs.

> Upon arrival, the police noticed a foul smell in the air.

Similarly, sometimes the article "a/an" is dropped.

Does this have a name? Lots of lawyers write this way, but I don't know if its a legitimate style or just bad form. I'm not referring to one line confirmations, as mentioned in a previous question.

Comment: There is another question about dropping articles in short confirmation responses. I added the additional information about where I normally see this phenomenon in order to distinguish this question from that question. My question ends with a question mark, the rest is just context.

Answer (score 8):

I am not sure whether there is a technical term, but legal writing is filled with specially defined terms. (Many legal writings have limits on length so there is a premium on eliminating excess words.) So "Defendant" with a capital letter may have been previously defined as "Ms. Maria J Smith residing at 343 Hill Street, Mobile, AL (hereafter the "Defendant.") In effect, "Defendant" with a capital now substitutes for "Maria J. Smith." We would not say " the Maria J. Smith."

Comment: Thats a good point. I think I've also seen it with works that are not defined terms, although I'm at a loss at the moment to find an example.

Comment: Sometimes those words are legal jargon, and tradition has set in about how they're used.

Comment: Same thing happens with *Buyer, Seller, Lessor, Lessee, Debtor, Creditor.* They are defined as referring to companies or individuals and are then used in the document as proper names that need not take the article to be sufficiently understood.

Comment: While that's true, I think the phenomenon the OP is discussing is more general, even in the context of law. The substitution / term of art hypothesis doesn't explain examples like "holding that a man who deliberately attacked a child on the playground satisfied the proximity element..." becoming "holding man's deliberate attack satisfied proximity element" which may, as the OP suggests, be bad style but, nevertheless, is quite common.